# How many subsets $S$ of $\{1, 2, \dots , n\}$ satisfy $S \cup (S + 1) = \{1, 2, \dots ,n\}$?

Tags: combinatorics

> For a set $S$ of integers, define $S + 1$ to be $\{x + 1 : x \in S \}$. How many subsets $S$ of $\{1, 2, \dots , n\}$ satisfy $S \cup (S + 1) = \{1, 2, \dots ,n\}$? Can you generalize this?

What I think is that we need always the condition that $1$ and $n-1$ are in the set $S$ as that's the only way for $1$ and $n$ to be in $S \cup (S+1)$.

For $n=1$ there is no such set as $S = \{1\}$, but $S+1 = \{2\}\Longrightarrow S \cup (S + 1) = \{1, 2\}\neq\{1\}$.

For $n=2$ there is only one subset that works i.e. $S = \{1\}$.

For $n=3$ I think that only $S =\{1,2\}$ works.

And lastly for $n=4$ I haven't computed all of the $16$ subsets, but I guess that the only ones working would be $S=\{1,3\}$ and $S=\{1,2,3\}$.

Is this a correct guess for the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you point out, $1$ and $n-1$ have to be in the set, so we're enumerating possibilities for the rest.

Suppose $n-2 \in S$. Then any combination of $\{2, \dots , n-3\}$ which would work for $n=k-1$ works for $k=n$, and only those work.

Suppose $n-2 \notin S$. Then $n-3 \in S$, and any combination of $\{2, \dots , n-4\}$ which would work for $n=k-2$ works for $k=n$, and only those work.

So we have the recurrence relation $a_{n+1} = a_n + a_{n-1}$. Note this recurrence relation hasn't been proved for all values, we need $n \ge 4$ I think. But it turns out to be true for all of them. We have the first terms of the sequence: $0,1,1,2$ and from there the recurrence relation takes over, so we have the Fibonacci sequence.

Answer (score 2):

Let $A_{n}$ be the number of good subsets for a given $n$. If $S$ is a good set for a given $n$, then $1\in S$. Unless $S=\{1, \cdots, n-1\}$ there must be some integers between $1$ and $n-1$ which are not in $S$. Let $k$ be the least element of $\{1,\cdots, n-1\}$ which is not in $S$.  Then the complement of $\{1, \cdots, k-1\}$ in $S$ must be a good set for $n-k$.

In a similar way, we can construct all the good sets for a given $n$ which omit some number $≤n-1$. And of course the set $S=\{1, \cdots, n-1\}$ is good for $n$.  Thus we have the recursion $$A_n=1+\sum_{k=2}^{n-2}A_k$$ and, with the given initial conditions, we do indeed get the Fibonacci numbers.